# How to check access rights, using Cypher, to assets to which users are note directly connected?

Tags: cypher, graph-databases, memgraphdb

We have a bunch of files and we want only users belonging to a certain department to have access to a specific set of files. We want to create a system that would upon swiping the card allows access to files.

I don't want to have multiple relations from each user to each file, but I'd rather have it compartmentalized.

What would Cypher query for this look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following command, you can now check the access rights of a person or department with a graph database.

The MATCH clause tries to find a pattern where the Person node with the usernaname “jsmith” and the File node with the name “apendix.pdf” are connected within 2 hops with relationships of type BELONGS_TO or HAS_ACCESS_TO.

In summary, the query checks if Mark BELONGS_TO a certain team which HAS_ACCESS_TO a file or whether there is a direct relationship between Person and File with HAS_ACCESS_TO type.

```
MATCH path=(p:Person {usernamename:"jsmith"})-[:BELONGS_TO|:HAS_ACCESS_TO *..2
]->(f:File {name:"apendix.pdf"})
RETURN *;
```